# MySQL query to get data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, Post and Cart, when a user adds an item which in this case is a post in the Post table, the Post id, post name and the user's name who has added it is added to the Cart table. What I want to do is when a user logs in, their username is matched with that in the Cart table retrieving the Post id and comparing the post id with that in the post table so that I can retrieve the whole post, below is a sketch of my tables

```
             Cart_item table
| item_id    | post_id     | username     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |        127  |     Chrome    


    Post Table
| post_id | make | price|seller|
|:--------|------|-----:|:----:|
| 127    |BMW   |$12000| Joan
```

The query should first look for a user in the Cart table, when it finds the user, it should then get all his Cart items which are his "post_ids" and match the post_ids with their corresponding ones in the Post table, if found, it should then retrieve the posts and show the user. How can I solve this? Can someone Help me I will Appreciate.

Comment: Use a join, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html `on post_table.post_id = cart_item.post_id` Presuming `This` in post table is actually `127`, `This` as an id isn't too useful.

Comment: I just edited it, I know I am suppose to use a join but how is the case, I cant figure out one query that will first compare the username to that in the Cart Table if found then get the post id and compare it to that in the Post table, if found then retrieve the entire post, I would appreciate if someone helped me.

Comment: The answer below isn't working?

Comment: it wasn't there when I commented, its working :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select post_table.* from post_table
left join cart_item on cart_item.post_id=post_table.post_id
where cart_item.username="Chrome";
```

Comment: Avoid using "*", you may bring innecesary data.

Comment: @Bhawin how exactly is this query working like? pardon me, I prefer learning so that next time I run in this kind of problem I will know my way out rather than asking for help again

Comment: yes , u can use post_table.make , post_table.price and so on ,  the answer is to make a point so that u get the solution , we dont spoon feed at stackoverflow ..

Comment: @user3105682   the query is a simple left join in mysql it just matches the username and gets thpost id from cart_item table and then search for that in post_table and prints that if exists

Comment: @Bhawin Parkeria Thank You, You just rescued me from 2hrs of pain

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is retrieve records in `Cast_item` table that have `Chrome` (or the user you are looking for) as `username` and then, join this table to the `Post` table with `post_id` key

```
select username, post.* 
from Cart_item
inner join Post on Cart_item.post_id=Post.post_id
where username="Chrome";
```